# How to change the name of application in validate diablog box?

Tags: xcode, bundle, identifier

I found a strange problem recently. I archived an iPad application, and, when I clicked the "validate..." button, I found the name of appliaction was the previous one (say it as B, and the application I wanna uploading is A.), and it was the only one, I couldn't change it.

However, the provisioning in the "identifier" matched the right application. If proceeded, the error is:

> Bundle Identifier com.xxx.A differs from Reserved Bundle Identifier com.xxx.B

How to fix this problem?